# echo output of logical expression in bash script ubuntu

Tags: bash, echo

```
var1 = 'abc'
var2 = 'bc'

echo "Print result: $[[$var1 =~ $var2]]"
```

This echo command is not working. How would I print the output of the logical expression `$var1 =~ $var2` correctly?

I want to check if var2 is a substring of var1. So the expected output would be "Print result: 1".

Comment: variable assignments don't take spaces in bash. It should be `var1='abc'` and `va2='bc'`

Comment: Yes, but that thas not solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it won't because `((` is the arithmetic operator in bash and regex matches are not supported within. You should use the extended test operator `[[` as `[[ $var1 =~ $var2 ]]`

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: `=~` is not a valid operator. What exactly are you going to calculate here?

Comment: Specify what output you would expect from the `echo`....

Comment: @Inian Using `echo "Print result: $[[ $var1 =~ $var2 ]]"`  is still not working. I expect the output to be "Print result: 1" in the example.

Comment: @user1934428 I want to have printed `Print result: 1`

Comment: Under what condition do you want to see an `1` printed? If `var2` is a substring of `var1`?  What do you want to see if the condition is not met? You need to specify these details in your question, if you want an answer. Since the code you posted, does not make any sense, we can not guess what you are looking for.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I want to check if var2 is a substring of var1. If not, the output should be "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Test whether var2 is a substring of var1
[[ $var1 == *$var2* ]]
# $? here is 0 if the condition is true and 1 if it is false.
# Set `result` to 1 if it is, and to 0 if it isn't
((result = 1 - $?))
```

This solves the problem as specified by the OP. However, I want to point
out that this way of modelling true/false is rather unusual. In most
cases, true would be modelled by 0 and false by 1.

Of course you don't need to use a variable, if you just want to `echo`:

```
[[ $var1 == *$var2* ]]
echo $((1 - $?))
```

Or you do it like this:

```
! [[ $var1 == *$var2* ]]
echo $?
```